# How to add multiple popup windows in one activity using Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, android-activity, popupwindow

i'm working on a simply starter app to get my feet wet with Android Studio 2.3. I'm a bit of a novice and i'm currently learning as I go. My issue is, trying to have multiple popup windows working properly in one java activity. Basically, I have two buttons in which I would like them to go to each separate xml. layout in which i'm using for my popup windows.

Now when I take the second popup window away of course everything works to perfection. However when I add my second popup window back (**as shown bellow**) my app crashes. I've tried changing (**"protected void" to "public void"**) as well as many other trial and error,YouTube etc. and have been stumped for days.

Please Help/
Again i'm a bit of a novice, so please forgive me in advance. Thank You

```
private Button vehicle_open;
private Button vehicletwo_open;

PopupWindow popupWindow;
PopupWindow popupWindow2;

LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shop_bay);

        vehicle_open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doorTouch);

        vehicle_open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_open, null);

                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 850, 390, true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(vehicle_open, Gravity.CENTER, 500, 500);

                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shop_bay);

        vehicletwo_open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trunkTouch);

        vehicletwo_open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                layoutInflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater2.inflate(R.layout.vehicletwo_open, null);

                popupWindow2 = new PopupWindow(container, 850, 390, true);
                popupWindow2.showAtLocation(vehicletwo_open, Gravity.LEFT, 500, 500);

                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        popupWindow2.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you mean one pop up after the other pop up?

Comment: Not necessarily. Picture one screen and two buttons on that screen. I'm trying to make the buttons work as popup windows. Think as of "hint" or "tip" kind of deal.

Comment: Post your shop_bay.xml also.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I actually figured it out last night. It was simple now that I have it. It was a matter of alignment within my brackets and removing this entire section. Now it works to perfection. Thanks again  **@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shop_bay);**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try alert builder code is here

```
 AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
    build.setTitle("Title");
    build.setCancelable(false);
    build.setMessage("Some Messages")
            .setPositiveButton("Button1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class));
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Button2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class))
        dialog.cancel();

    }).show();
```